# How to configure two STS gradle projects in eclipse to use another STS gradle project?

Tags: gradle, spring-tool-suite, gradle-eclipse

I have a two spring boot applications. Each application is setup as a separate eclipse project. Let's call them project A and project B. I also have another project C that contains domain classes. Project A and B need to use project C. All projects are in the same eclipse (Mars.1 Release 4.5.1) workspace.

Per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29634854/1706691) and this [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/129267-how-to-use-remap-jars-to-maven-projects-feature), I have

1. Created a pom.xml at the root of project C and typed mvn install
2. I have checked "Remap Jars to maven projects", "Remap Jars to Gradle Projects", and "Use Custom Tooling Model" under Window -> Preferences -> Gradle
3. From the context menu for each project, clicked Gradle -> Enable Dependency Management.
4. From the context menu for each project, clicked Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies.

After making changes to a domain class in project C and clean and build project C, I clean, build and bootRun project A or B and notice that the changes in project C are not present.

How can I properly configure remapping of jars to gradle projects so that changes in project C are reflected in A and B without having to reinstall to the local maven repo?

I'm using SpringSource Tool Suite Gradle Integration 3.7.2.

Comment: It sounds like you did everything correctly. Not sure why it isn't working. Do you have sample projects? If I can try it myself maybe I can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Kris. The sample projects are located at https://github.com/logicg8/remap-jars-to-gradle-projects

Comment: I've tried your projects for a bit and it indeed doesn't seem to remap the 'c' project jar. I don't know yet why. I will debug it a little when I have some more time.